# Script to dynamically change the source of an iframe tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, xhtml

I want a code that will dynamically change the source of an iframe tag when a hyperlink is clicked for example I have one master page that should load content from other web pages using the iframe tag when a hyperlink is clicked but I don't know how to do it. Here is my code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
    </title>

    <style type="text/css">
      #content {
        margin-right:30%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        margin-left: 17%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 686;
        height: 640;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function hyperlinkChanger(hyperLink) 
      {

        switch (hyperLink)
        {

          case "home":
            var url="home.html";
            return url;
            break;

          case "about_Us":
            var url="about_us.html";
            return url;

            break;

          case "contact_Us:
            var url="contact_us.html";
            return url;

            break;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="home.html" name="home" onClick="hyperlinkChanger('home')">Home</a>
    <br />
    <a href="about_us.html" name="about_Us" onClick="hyperlinkChanger('about_Us')">About Us</a>
    <br />
    <a href="contact_us.html" name="contact_Us" onClick="hyperlinkChanger('contact_Us')">Contact us</a>
    <br />

    <div name="content">
      <!--please help me write a method to call the output of the funcion hyperlinkChanger-->
      <iframe src="hyprlink function" width="600" height="300">
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sans javascript:

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe id="foo"></iframe>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240078/script-to-dynamically-change-the-source-of-an-iframe-tag" target="foo">This page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

You can target local or external links. Notice that in this example, javascript running on Stack Overflow detects its page is being loaded in an iframe and puts out a notice to the user. Some sites don't some do. There are even techniques to detect if your page is being loaded into an iframe and redirect the parent page to your site directly instead. If all you're doing is loading your own pages, though, you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: Tis a dynamic page. I want one master page to be displaying other pages in an iframe when a link is clicked.

Comment: Ok, then just update the href of your anchors. Tis all you have to do.

Comment: Thats what I don't know how to in javascript

Comment: I've already answered your question. You don't need to use javascript at all for this. Give your iframe an id. Then simply add the attribute target="<id>" to each of your anchors, where <id> is the id of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why do it with JAVASCRIPT? 
You can just use the target-attribute on the a-element!

But if you have to use javascript do something like this:
declare var url = ''; before the switch statement 
Remove the returns from you switch cases
An after the switch statement add this: $('iframe').attr('src', url);

Comment: Why the down-vote? Just give the iframe an id, and construct the a-element like this: '<a href="http://google.com/" target="[iframe-id]">open google in iframe with id [iframe-id]</a>' Just replace the [iframe-id] with the name of your choice